# get values from checkboxes in django

Tags: python, django, generics

I have several checkboxes from bootstrap and I need to get their vaules in my django app. I've tried to read them by using request.GET.get_list but all it does is returning an empy list. POST doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

persl.html:

```
 {% for l in pl %}
  <tr>
<td><div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checks" value="value" id="fs">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="checks">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
    <td><a href="pupdate/{{l.pk}}"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a></td>
    <td><a href="pdelete/{{l.pk}}"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></a></td>
    <td>{{l.pk}}</td>
    <td><a href="detail/{{l.padress.pk}}">{{l.fname}}</a></td>
    <td>{{l.lname}}</td>
    <td>{{l.mobil}}</td>
    <td>{{l.mail}}</td>
    <td>{{l.padress}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
class PDelete(DeleteView):

    template_name='kammem/delete.html'
    model=Person
    success_url=reverse_lazy('personer')

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            v=self.request.GET.getlist('checks')
        return v
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML `<form>`?

Comment: there is no <form>.... persl.html is the template that is rendered. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @JonasFrederiksson: without a `form` you will simply never make a POST request, and a GET request is not supposed to have any side-effects, so the `DeleteView` will not work: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/a-get-request-with-side-effects.html.

Comment: ok, I see. I have to add a form, I thought the above solution could give just the checkbox values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a delete removes items, you need to do this through a POST or DELETE request, not a GET request.

A `DeleteView` does *not* delete items in bulk, it is implemented to delete a *single* object. We thus have to implement our own view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.edit import DeletionMixin

class PDeleteBulkView(DeletionMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name='kammem/delete.html'
    model=Person
    success_url=reverse_lazy('personer')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        Person.objects.filter(
            pk__in=self.request.POST.getlist('checks')
        ).delete()
        return return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

In the HTML form, you thus should make a POST request to the `PDeleteView`:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% URL 'name-of-pdelete-bulk-view' %}">
    … table …
    <button type="submit">delete</button>
</form>
```

here the checkboxes will thus, if checked add data to the `checks` item. If you then click the `delete` button, you will make a POST request to the `PDeleteBulkView` that will remove the items in bulk.

Note that we here do not check any permissions, we thus assume that the user can delete these items. Furthermore we do not check if the primary keys are all items that "belong" to the user, a user can thus fabricate a POST request and remove other items. You will thus need to add security, for example by filtering the queryset such that only items for which the user is the "owner" can be removed.